# How I can make multi language program?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm new in programming I knew some programming languages. 
When I search anything about any program it is written in more than one programming language.
How can I do it. And it is important to use multi languages to make a advanced programs?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant applications or systems; You can technically a whole system that you want in some lower-level languages, it's a matter of practicality, some tools and programming languages are domain-specific and excel at specific use-cases. Not sure what you're asking though, if you're new to programming, read more about software architecture and stuff alike before you dive into writing multi-paradigm and multi-language applications.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Trying to break your questions apart: _How can I do it_: What exactly have you tried and what is the actual problem? _And it is important to use multi languages to make a advanced programs_ : What program are you trying to build and what should it do? What are the requirements (functional and non-functional) for this program?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typically programs are written in modules of some kinds. There are various ways to let communicate between modules:

1. [RPC frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). This would typically involve serializing all parameters and responses, and sending it over some network (or IPC) connection. This is a very generic method, and works between most languages, but can be difficult to use, and may be slower.
2. C calls. Many languages support calling native C code. One of the limitations is poor support for object orientated code.
3. [Microsoft COM.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) This allows objects to be shared between modules written in different programming languages. Only for Windows as far as I know.
4. [.Net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) & [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)). These define a standard for representing objects and code in a language and machine-independent way. Both support multiple different programming languages. This is generally easier to use than the other technologies. .Net and Java are not interoperable but uses very similar designs. Both works on multiple platforms.

Regardless of method, using multiple languages requires maintaining multiple different code bases, often with different tool chains, and might require developers to be competent in both languages. Therefore it is usually only done when there is a specific need, like integrating third party components, combining an language that is easy to use with a high performance language ( as used for some games ), or for legacy reasons.